# Calling AsyncTask not functioning

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I have set up an AsyncTask class to do some things in the background for me so the UI doesn't freeze when downloading the image to then set as wallpaper.

When calling my AsyncTask class from an onItemCLick, I get an error.

The error states "The constructor SetWallpaperAsync(ImageDetailFragment) is undefined"

I am relatively new with working with AsyncTask so would someone check my codes and tell me where I am going wrong, much appreciated, thank you.

Calling from this class(ImageDetailFragment):

```
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    // TODO Add your menu entries here
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.image_menu, menu);

}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.Favoritewallpaper:



    case R.id.Setwallpaper:

        new SetWallpaperAsync(this).execute(mImageUrl); // <-------- Here - "The constructor SetWallpaperAsync(ImageDetailFragment) is undefined"

    }

    return true;
}
```

SetWallpaperAsync:

```
public class SetWallpaperAsync extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
private Context context;
private ProgressDialog pDialog;
String image_url;
URL mImageUrl;
String myFileUrl1;
Bitmap bmImg = null;

public SetWallpaperAsync(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    super.onPreExecute();

    pDialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
    pDialog.setMessage("Setting Wallpaper...");
    pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
    pDialog.setCancelable(false);
    pDialog.show();

}

@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    try {

        mImageUrl = new URL(args[0]);
        // myFileUrl1 = args[0];

        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) mImageUrl
                .openConnection();
        conn.setDoInput(true);
        conn.connect();
        InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
        bmImg = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return null;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    WallpaperManager wpm = WallpaperManager.getInstance(context);
    try {
        wpm.setBitmap(bmImg);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    pDialog.dismiss();

}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace

```
new SetWallpaperAsync(this).execute(mImageUrl);
```

with this,

```
new SetWallpaperAsync(getActivity()).execute(mImageUrl);
```

Answer (score 1):

looks like `ImageDetailFragment` cannot be used as Activity/Context. If this is some custom library, you may find some methods like `getActivity()` or `getContext()`

```
new SetWallpaperAsync(this.getActivity()).execute(mImageUrl); //or this.getContext()
```